# How to remove anchor of arView.session.currentFrame?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, lidar

Recently, I studied about ARWorldTrackingConfiguration. But it is very difficult. First I want to use this function:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) { }
```

I already tried these one but it's not working:

```
arView.session.remove(anchor: frame.anchors[0])
arView.session.currentFrame?.anchors.removeAll() // 'anchors' is a get-only property
```

Anyone know about 'didRemove' of session function by using something?

Plz help me master of ARkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove ARAnchor from ARSession you need to use [remove(anchor:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2865607-remove) instance method:

```
let specialAnchor = ARAnchor(name: "special", transform: simd_float4x4())

arView.session.remove(anchor: specialAnchor)
```

The method you've mentioned is called when anchors are removed from the session:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    self.anchorsData(anchors: anchors)
}

func anchorsData(anchors: [ARAnchor]) -> [Any] {
    var data = [Any]()
    // some code...
    return data
}
```

Comment: Thanks your comment I used arView.session.remove but It occured flickeringly mesh map. Did you know about session remove before apear session update